# How do I stop watermarking videos with this ffmpeg command line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to remove the code that adds a watermark to some of our videos, but can't find the correct solution

Working with pre-existing code. I am unfamiliar with bash and ffmpeg. We are trying to remove the code that adds a watermark to certain videos. There are plenty of examples on how to add the watermark. But using them to figure out how to remove it has been unsuccessful.

Original Code

```sh
FFREPORT=file=$folder/ffmpeg.log:level=40 ~/tools/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -ss $startTime -i $folder/0 -i assets/watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size1w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size1h)'[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=20:(main_h-overlay_h-20),split=5[in1][in2][in3][in4][in5];[in1]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size1w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size1h)'[out1];[in2]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size2w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size2h)'[out2];[in3]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size3w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size3h)'[out3];[in4]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size4w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size4h)'[out4];[in5]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size4w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size4h)'[out5]" \
```

Attempted Change

I removed `-i assets/watermark.png` and `[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=20:(main_h-overlay_h-20),`

```
FFREPORT=file=$folder/ffmpeg.log:level=40 ~/tools/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -ss $startTime -i $folder/0 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size1w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size1h)';split=5[in1][in2][in3][in4][in5];[in1]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size1w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size1h)'[out1];[in2]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size2w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size2h)'[out2];[in3]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size3w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size3h)'[out3];[in4]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size4w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size4h)'[out4];[in5]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size4w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size4h)'[out5]" \
```

The error I'm getting is

> Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_split_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect the split using a comma since the split will directly operate upon the output of the scale.

`[0:v]scale='if(gt(iw,ih),$size1w,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,$size1h)',split=5[in1][in2][in3][in4][in5];`